# How do I define that an attribute should be unique within a given scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a set of authors, with each author having a unique name.  That uniqueness validation is quite easy.

Each author should have a number of stories, each story requiring a title that must be unique for the author.  So it's completely legal to have two stories with an identical title, so long as they are written by different authors.  Two stories sharing a title by the same author is illegal.

I can't use `validates :title, :uniqueness=>true` because then I can't have the same title shared by two different authors.  Do I need to write a custom validator that iterates over every title by the author, or are there better options available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the scope option on the uniqueness validator:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: {scope: :author_id}
```

Comment: As I thought, there was an insanely simple and obvious option available.